# use vba to create word-document label.list and fill it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use my excel sheet to use a vba-macro. The macro create a new word-document and by use a mailing-label id.
Now i want to fill the label with some data from my exel sheet. I tried it with an array.
My idea would looks like:
1. create Word object
2. create mailing.label
3. load my excel vba-array by loop into the mailing.label

my code to create the document

```
Sub test()

Dim oDoc As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set appwd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set appwd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With appwd
        If .Documents.Count = 0 Then
            .Documents.Add
        End If
        Set oDoc = .MailingLabel.CreateNewDocumentByID(LabelID:="1359804674")
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        'Do stuff with oDoc here
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ... so your question is.. ? || btw.. I find that what you want to achieve is similar to "Insert Merge Field" built-in Ms Word function.. Just clicks.. no script needed. ( :

Comment: I don't pass it.... I tried it for a long time. Now i tried to create a word with a table(which has the same style, like the lable).

Comment: The srcipt in my first post works great. But how can i fill some value in the cells? 
I need to write in the first cell: "apple", in the second cell:"banana", in the third cell: "strabwerry"......
I have all datas in a array

Comment: you should include that info/example in the 1st post.. ( :